# Deploying a churn prediction model

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, panel-data, churn

When deploying models such as churn prediction models how do you deal with the fact the you are constantly predicting on observations you previously trained on?

I have an employee churn prediction model that achieves good test results in predicting who is going to leave in the next X months. I have timeseries data from 01/01/2015 to 31/12/2019. I reserve 80% of the employees for the training set and 20% for the test set.

My problem is: I want to put this model into production so that it can predict who is going to churn , for example in the first 3 months of the year, so I would want to use this model in 01/01/2020. However since the model is predicting on the same employees it was previously trained on my results are not good. I've tried leaving a certain space between the training and the prediction but it still does not achieve good results.

Comment: What is the model you're fitting?

Comment: An LSTM neural net to deal with sequence data. I've also tried other models